# How do i flash my android device ROM to uninstall King root 4.8.0?

Tags: rom-flashing, huawei

My android device is a Huawei Ascend G7-L01
I downloaded King root 4.8.0 like one year ago,when i was fed up of it,it tried to uninstall it,didn't work claiming that it is a system app,then i did a factory reset,did't work again,then i tried to uninstall it inside the app itself and it said 'removing failed feedback',didn't work again, and i disabled it but it does still affect the phone and it is annoying ,then many people were suggesting flash the android device ROM...........

My problem here is i don't know if it will really work and how to use it , can you guys please specify your answer ?

Comment: I guess what you're missing is some background on [what a ROM is](/tags/rom/info) and [what ROM-flashing means](/tags/rom-flashing/info) (please follow the links, both are "quick reads" with useful links). With that obtained, your question is as good as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Download ES File explorer, grant it root permissions and:

```
 1. Delete the app from /system/app/Kingroot
 2. Delete the su file from /system/bin
 3. Reboot the phone
```

That is if you can't do just as my friend already told you

Comment: When i  tried to delete the app from /system/app/kingroot ,it said  'kingroot uninstall failed'. plz help

Answer (score 0):

That is from the Kingroot app itself you're talking about, but from a third party file manager like ES it can surely remove it off in a second. But incase it doesn't you can try adb if you access a laptop with ADB tool where you will connect your phone to, authorize debugging from your phone and run these commands:

```
adb shell
su
rm /system/app/Kingroot/Kingroot.apk
```

or download an app called terminal emulator to phone then run the commands directly:

```
    su
    rm /system/app/Kingroot/Kingroot.apk
```

This will delete the app away as easy as abc. after allowing the prompt of terminal to use root access